# Не работает Exception

Tags: java, android

Почему когда c условием в методе clickEquals при делении на ноль выходит из приложения(В приложении 'Calculyator' произошла ошибка),а без нее выводит Error как я хочу.

```
public String operator(String a, String b, String op) {
    double a1 = Double.valueOf(a);
    double b1 = Double.valueOf(b);
    double res = 0;
    try {
        switch (op) {
            case "+":
                res = a1 + b1;
                return String.valueOf(res);
            case "-":
                res = a1 - b1;
                return String.valueOf(res);

            case "*":
                res = a1 * b1;
                return String.valueOf(res);

            case "/":
                if (b1 != 0) {
                    res = a1 / b1;
                    return String.valueOf(res);
                } else
                    return "Error";
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return String.valueOf(res);
    }

  public boolean getResult() {
      String[] operation = display.split(Pattern.quote(currentOperation));
      if (operation.length<2)
          return false;

      result = operator(operation[0], operation[1], currentOperation);
      return true;
  }
  public void clickEquals(View v) {
      if (!getResult())
          return;
      else
          txtv.setText(display + "=" + result);
  }
```

Comment: Как это выходит из программы? Опишите это более детально

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov изменила вопрос

Comment: а можете логи добавить, потому-что немного сложно понять какая ошибка и тем более как ее исправить без кода ошибки?

Comment: Как-то вы условия в ``if`` в clickEquals вопреки здравому пониманию сделали. Логически все правильно, но голову свернешь, пока разберешься.

Comment: Дайте пример ввода для обоих случаев.

Comment: У меня   результат имеет тип  double и выводит к примеру 25.0, я удаляю последние 2 элемента(. и 0) чтоб 25 было.Когда я делаю это всё работает кроме деления на 0.